# Converting text into list where it has spaces

Tags: python

How can I convert text into separate lists where it has a spaces?

```
text=input('Input your text: ')
length=len(text.split())
print(length)
list(text)
```

Comment: could you please share a sample that you want? I did not understand the question properly

Answer (score -1):

yes you can by doing :

```py
text = input('Input your text: ')
split_text = text.split()
length=len(split_text)
print(length)
print(split_text)
a = input('')
```